# Why is this code inside a Spark map function still cached, even though a class that is referenced there has changed?

Tags: java, apache-spark, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm using Spark 2.4.5 with Java 8 in Standalone Mode and I'm converting a CSV file to a Spark Dataset like so:

```
sparkSession.read().csv("foo.csv").map((MapFunction<Row, MyBean>) row -> {
  MyBean bean = new MyBean();
  bean.setFoo(row.getAs("foo"));
  bean.setBar(row.getAs("bar"));
  return bean;
}, Encoders.bean(MyBean.class));
```

The `MyBean` class contains some code that is generated with lombok and is defined in another Java project that is available in my local maven artifactory. Now I changed something unrelated in that `MyBean` class, ran `mvn install` and suddenly I got a `NoSuchMethodError`: `setFoo` is undefined.

I suspected an issue with the code generated by lombok, so I fiddled around with it, but nothing seemed to work, until I just removed the line that contains `setFoo` in the map function. Weird, so all the other setters are fine, only this one is missing? So I added `setFoo` again, expecting it to fail, but surprisingly *it worked*.

To me it seems like there must be some kind of cache of just the code inside this map function and somehow the references to the setters got messed up when the `MyBean` class changed and lombok rearranged all the functions. And by changing some code inside the map function, I invalidated the cache and that fixed it. But where does this cache come from? Is Spark caching the code inside the map function somewhere? Is IntelliJ doing this? I really need to be able to test the code I'm working on and not some old cached version of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try considering `-U` option when doing the `mvn install` command. So your desired command after making the change is `mvn install -U`

```
 -U,--update-snapshots                  Forces a check for missing
                                        releases and updated snapshots on
                                        remote repositories
```

I had also faced this problem long back that when you change the code in another repository, it creates a problem in the current repository and after some time(By invalidating cache and restart option) it starts working properly.

After I started using the above option of `mvn`, I had not faced the problem till now.

Comment: that's good to know, but does this also apply when I install the project locally? the way I understand it, `--update-snapshots` forces maven to download snapshots from a remote artifactory. I'm installing the dependencies locally and I'm not using snapshot versions.

Comment: In my understanding, it does apply to the project locally.